# How can I count the object with condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Community** has_many :codes
**Code** belongs_to :community

**User** has_many :codes
**Code** belongs_to :user

```
@community.codes.users.count
```

This returns the number of users whose code is belonging to the community.

**Code** has the column called `visible` as boolean

what if I only want to count the number of the users whose code with true on `visible`, that is belonging to the community?

Is it possible to count that?

I mean, I'd like to obtain the number of the count that's calculated just like this below.
I want it in one line.

```
@community.codes.each do |code|
    if code.visible && code.user
        count = count + 1
    end
end
```

Comment: Please provide an example to make your question clear

Comment: @eneskaya Thanks for a comment. I described an example:)

Comment: Okay, let's think about this way. @communities are states just like California, New York and etc... Code stands for flight ticket to those states.  The user has bought many tickets to all over the states, and the number of tickets how they are bought is depending on each user. Here, I'd like to count the number of the user who has bought the tickets to California(@community), and ticket is saved as invisible to other users. Does this make any sense?

Comment: couldn't it be something like this? `@count = @community.codes.where(:visible => true).users.count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is equivalent to what you need. It will give the exact result.

```
User.joins(:codes => :community).where("codes.visible=? AND communities.id=?", true, @community.id).count
```

There is also another better aproach. You should use namedscope for such types queries so that you can use it multiple times where you need:

In User model:

```
scope :visible_in_community, (lambda do |community_id|
  joins(:codes => :community).where("codes.visible=? AND communities.id=?", true, community_id) 
end)
```

And you can call anywhere

```
User.visible_in_community(@community.id)
```

Comment: Your one is the best because in the other 2 answers, when the user is deleted and there are still Codes, it still counts... But with your code, when the user is deleted it won't count him anymore. That's what I wanted. Thanks:)

Comment: One more question plz!!! if I had another model called `Profile` and it has the boolean column called `notification`. Then User has_one :profile, Profile belongs_to :user.  How can I add this condition to yours? I mean. it shouldn't count when if the user.profile.notification is false. Can you show me how?

Comment: It is NOT better approach. It is faster. Better will be creating `self.visible_in_community` method. See Rails Guides [ActiveRecord Querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) section §13.2

Comment: @cat: I think it will work for you: User.joins(:profile).joins(:codes => :community).where("codes.visible=? AND profiles.notification=? AND communities.id=?", true, true, @community.id).count

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will works for you.

```
@community.codes.where('visible = ? AND user_id IS NOT NULL', true).count
```

Answer (score 1):

The following line is equivalent to the last piece of code of your question, but more efficient because in a single SQL request: get the count visible `Code` with a `User` and that belong to `@community`

```
Code.where('visible = ? AND community_id = ? AND user_id IS NOT NULL', true, @community.id).count
```